# save data of a particular row of a table using index in angular

Tags: angular, grid

I'm showing data from service in grid.
I'm showing data from studentsInfo array using ngfor in grid.
Records with status 'Y' will be shown as present.
Records with status N will be coming with a button "click to present".
Now, i'm trying to to implement add functionality for records in the grid using index, on click of the button for only that particular record having a button..
I used formgroup: SearchForm, to submit the values.
I only need to send the values of id and roll_no only while adding, as service is designed only for those 2 fields.
As, of now, when i click on the button, i'm getting empty values.
Please help me achieve the functionality.

```
 
        <table style="width: 1000px; float: left">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td>
                <div *ngIf="showdata == true">
                  <table>
                  
                    <thead>
                    
                      <tr>
                     
                        <th>  Id    </th>
                        <th>  name    </th>
                        <th>  Roll_no    </th>
                        <th>  section_name    </th>
                        <th>  Status    </th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    </thead>
                  </table>
                  
                  <form [formGroup]="SearchForm" >
                  <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px">
                    <div class="contentss">
                      <table>
                        <tbody>
                          <ng-container *ngIf="studentsInfo| Filter : Srch: Columns :'abc' as studentData; else noItems">
                          <tr *ngFor="let list of studentData ; let i = index">
                          
                            <td style="width: 100px">
                              <div style="margin-left: 50px">
                                <span>{{ i }}</span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                              <div>
                                <span formControlName="id" name="id" ngDefaultContro>{{ list.Id }}</span>
                              </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                              <div>
                                <span>{{ list.name }}</span>
                              </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                              <div>
                                <span formControlName="Roll_no" name="Roll_no">{{ list.Roll_no }}</span>
                              </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                              <div>
                                <span>{{ list.section_name }}</span>
                              </div>
                            </td>

                            <td *ngIf=" list.Status === 'Y'; else elseBlock">

                            <div>
                              <span>Present</span>
                            </div>
                            </td>

                          <ng-template #elseBlock>
                            <td >
                              <div>                               
                                <span>
                                  <input type="submit" value="Click to present" ((click)="onAcceptClick(i)">  
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </ng-template>
 

                          </tr>
                          <ng-container *ngIf="!studentData.length && hide" [ngTemplateOutlet]="noItems"></ng-container>
                          </ng-container>
                          <ng-template #noItems>
                                <tr><td colspan="9" style="text-align: center;">No students Available!</td></tr>
                          </ng-template>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

```
studentsInfo: any = [];


 id: number;
 studentList(id){
    const obj = {
      ID: this.selected
    };
  this.inceSrvc.postmethod('students/get',obj).subscribe((res:any)=>{
   if (res.status === 200) {
     const students = res.response;
     if (students) {
       this.studentsInfo = res.response;
     }
}
 });
}
 

  SearchForm: FormGroup;
    public globalResponse: any = [];

    onAcceptClick(){
      if (this.SearchForm.invalid) {
        alert('Please check the details');
       return;
      }

      const obj = {
        id : this.SearchForm.value.id,
        roll_no : this.SearchForm.value.roll_no,
      }
     this.inceSrvc.postmethod('students',this.SearchForm.value).subscribe((response:any)=>{
        this.globalResponse = response;
        if(this.globalResponse.status === 200)
        {
          alert('Record updated');       
        }
   });
  }

}
```

service that is body of api,

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "roll_no": "21"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a form is not the correct approach here. What you essentially have in your code is a list of students, and your form is set up to capture a single set of values.

All you need is a button, through which you would need pass on the "id" and "roll_no" from the corresponding row and send it across to your method on your component.

So get rid of the form tag in the HTML, and the corresponding formGroup definition in the TS file.

As a rough example, see sample code below:

```
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <td >
    <div>                               
      <span>
        <button type="button" (click)="onAcceptClick(i, list.Id, list.Roll_no)">Click to present</button>  
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-template>
```

On your TS file:

```
onAcceptClick(index: number, id: string, roll_no: string) {
  if (!index || !id || !roll_no) {
    return alert('Please check');
  }
  // rest of your code with index value
}
```

So your HTML will be like:

```
table >
row1 > index 0 > id 100 > roll_no 121 > button(0, 100, 121)
row2 > index 1 > id 100 > roll_no 122 > button(1, 100, 122)
row3 > index 2 > id 100 > roll_no 122 > button(2, 100, 123)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but, Actually, here ID is same for all the students. As i'm getting it from a different table in database. I want to the send the value of id and roll_no of a particular index only. I feel grateful if you  please elaborate the answer with my code. As i'm new to coding.

Comment: When you use a *ngFor loop in your template, it displays a list of all the students. The button is displayed for each row in your table (if not explicitly hidden). So each button will capture the id and roll_no for the corresponding student only. You can pass as many parameters as you need inside your function. I have edited my answer to pass index as well.

Comment: so, when i donot use form, how can i send the values of selected row in obj, sir ?

Comment: A button click is sufficient for your requirement. The (click) attribute on a button calls a method in your TS file, and you can pass as many arguments as you need from your HTML to your TS method. I have edited my initial response and you can look at the button code.

Comment: const obj = {
        id: id,
        roll_no: roll_no,
      }
is this okay ? This is what my doubt is Sir. Is this correct way to send values of id and roll_no in obj for service ?

Comment: Yes absolutely. That's how you should create the object from the values you receive in the onAcceptClick method in the TS file.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, then please consider marking this as the answer. That would close this thread.